# Label rows of a matrix in the presence of other matrices

Tags: matrices

I have multiple matrices placed next to each other. I would like to label the rows of the matrix on the right-hand side (a label outside of the matrix). For example, I would like to put those *Con \eqref{eq4}* outside of the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{40}
\begin{landscape}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{00}\\
x_{01}\\
x_{02}\\
x_{03}\\
\vdots\\
x_{10}\\
x_{11}\\
x_{12}\\
x_{13}\\
\vdots\\
x_{(10)0}\\
x_{(10)1}\\
x_{(10)2}\\
x_{(10)3}\\
\vdots\\
w_0\\
w_1\\
w_2\\
w_3\\
\vdots\\
w_{10}
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\leq 1 & \text{Con} \eqref{eq4}\\
\leq 1 & \text{Con} \eqref{eq4}\\
\leq 1 \\
\vdots\\
\leq 1\\
\leq 1\\
\leq 1\\
\vdots\\
=1\\
=1\\
=0\\
=0\\
=0\\
=0\\
\vdots\\
\geq g_1-M\\
\geq g_2-M\\
\geq g_3-M\\
\vdots\\
=0\\
\leq C_1\\
\leq C_1\\
\leq C_1\\
\vdots\\
\leq C_1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use "long stacks" (that have a fixed baselineskip) as part of the `tabstackengine` package, then setting multiple column vectors to the right will automatically align vertically.   `\<prefix>Matrixstack` and `\<prefix>Vectorstack` are instances of long stacks, where `<prefix>` can be left blank or `paren`, `bracket`, `vert` or `brace`.

inter-column gaps and inter-row baselineskips can be set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{40}
\begin{landscape}
\setstackgap{L}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}% INTER-ROW BASELINESKI{P
\setstacktabbedgap{8pt}% INTER-COLUMN GAP
\[
\bracketMatrixstack{
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0
}
%
\bracketVectorstack{
x_{00}\\
x_{01}\\
x_{02}\\
x_{03}\\
\vdots\\
x_{10}\\
x_{11}\\
x_{12}\\
x_{13}\\
\vdots\\
x_{(10)0}\\
x_{(10)1}\\
x_{(10)2}\\
x_{(10)3}\\
\vdots\\
w_0\\
w_1\\
w_2\\
w_3\\
\vdots\\
w_{10}
}
%
\bracketVectorstack{
\leq 1 \\
\leq 1 \\
\leq 1 \\
\vdots\\
\leq 1\\
\leq 1\\
\leq 1\\
\vdots\\
=1\\
=1\\
=0\\
=0\\
=0\\
=0\\
\vdots\\
\geq g_1-M\\
\geq g_2-M\\
\geq g_3-M\\
\vdots\\
=0\\
\leq C_1\\
\leq C_1\\
\leq C_1\\
\vdots\\
\leq C_1
}
\Vectorstack{
\text{Con} \eqref{eq4}\\
\text{Con} \eqref{eq4}\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
}
\]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]